changing a file name using information in a .txt file
I raised this question edit file names using separate txt file information in R or bash
And got very helpful answers
I made an edit to the question but was advised to post a new question, which I had previously presumed would get me downvoted.
I have a txt file with CHEM_ID and COMP_ID columns. These looks like:
CHEM_ID     COMP_ID
M35         metmss_42370
M501        metmss_485
M555555     metmss_27665

Separately to this txt file, I have hundreds of files which I want to amend the file names of, using this txt file information. Currently, these files have the following names:
BIB.metmss_42370.european-2024-03-04.txt.gz

And so on, where each 'metmss_xxxx' number is different.
Can I edit these file names, [in R ideally], so that they also include the corresponding CHEM_ID [as specified in the txt file above] 'metmss' is replaced with 'C'.
e.g. where CHEM_ID is M35 - the one which corresponds to metmss_42370
BIB.M35.C42370.european-2024-03-04.txt.gz

I was given a great solution in the previous post
> fnm <- list.files(pattern='^BIB', full.names=TRUE)
> ids <- read.table('foo.txt', header=TRUE)  ## file w/ ID columns
> lapply(seq_len(nrow(ids)), \(i) {
+   old <- fnm[grep(ids$COMP_ID[i], fnm)]
+   new <- sub('metmss_', sprintf('%s.C', ids$CHEM_ID[i]), old)
+   file.rename(old, new)
+ })

Then I went on to make some edits of my own to further change the file names:
fnm <- list.files(pattern='^BIB', full.names=TRUE)
ids <- read.table('../../../../../../data/compid_chemid.txt', header=TRUE)
for (i in seq_len(nrow(ids))) {
  old <- fnm[grep(ids$COMP_ID[i], fnm)]
  new <- sub('metmss_', paste0(ids$CHEM_ID[i], '_C'), old)
  new <- sub('BIB.', '', new)  
  new <- sub('(european)-(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})', 'BIB_EUR_SAIGE_GRCh37_\\2', new)  
  new <- gsub('-', '', new) 
  file.rename(old, new)
}

So they looked like:
M35_C42370.BIB_EUR_SAIGE_GRCh37_20240304.txt.gz

However, now it incorrectly names some of the files. I want to match exactly on the existing COMP_ID and CHEM_ID, but my code has some incorrect pattern matching. An example I have found is for M561 - the correct ID is C57, but it has also matched the M* ID to other IDs with 'C57' in the name
M561_C57.BIB_EUR_SAIGE_GRCh37_20240304.txt.gz
M561_C57331.BIB_EUR_SAIGE_GRCh37_20240304.txt.gz
M561_C57369.BIB_EUR_SAIGE_GRCh37_20240304.txt.gz
M561_C57372.BIB_EUR_SAIGE_GRCh37_20240304.txt.gz 

Can someone help me get around this? So each of these files given as an example above would have the correct CHEM_ID [as specified in the original txt file - they are all unique matches with no duplicates]
Many thanks in advance

Probably a regex pattern like   C[0-9]{2,2}[.]   to require  exactly two numerals and then a period.

Not all the IDs have 2 numerals, they have up to 9. Will make that clearer in my post.

OK, then,  C[0-9]{1,9}[.]

I guess your problem comes from the fact that some keys are contained in other keys and your regex catches those as well. But htis is pure guesswork, as I do not know your full key file.
Anyways, I propose the following approach:

First, you extract the metmss_<number> part for each file. This is the key which you want to join your CHEM_ID to. (assumption <number> consist only of numbers and no alphanumerical characters are part of it)
From the key you build your specific regex search string, that is metmss_485 becomes metmss_(485) (note the parenthesis). This allows to extract the number later. And you construct your regex replacement string .C\\1 which tells the replace later to replace metmss_(485) by .C485.
Now that you have your search and replacement regexes you just need to use them, the rest is stripping and replacement of other unwanted elements.

N.B. I used tidyverse syntax for convenience, everything could also be done with base R. Furthermore, I decded to work with a data.frame as it makes it easy to see all the intermediate steps simply by printing fns_df_ammended.
library(here)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

###############################################################
#### BEGIN SETUP
###############################################################

## create some mock up files
files_dir <- here("rename_files")
if (!dir.exists(files_dir)) {
  dir.create(files_dir)
  dir.create(file.path(files_dir, "renamed"))
}

some_files <- c("BIB.metmss_42370.european-2024-03-04.txt.gz",
                "BIB.metmss_485.european-2024-03-04.txt.gz",
                "BIB.metmss_27665.european-2024-03-04.txt.gz",
                "BIB.metmss_4851.european-2024-03-04.txt.gz")

## create mockup replacement table
replace_fn <- here("compid_chemid.txt")
cat(
  "CHEM_ID     COMP_ID
M35         metmss_42370
M501        metmss_485
M555555     metmss_27665
M145        metmss_4851  
", 
  file = replace_fn)

fns <- vapply(some_files, \(fn) {
  ffn <- file.path(files_dir, fn)
  cat("test", file = ffn)
  ffn
}, character(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

###############################################################
#### END SETUP
###############################################################

## create tibble with columns with the needed elements
fns_df <- tibble(full_path = fns) %>% 
  mutate(key = str_extract(basename(full_path), "^BIB\\.(.+\\d+)", 1))

## read replacement table
replacement_table <- read.table(replace_fn, header = TRUE)

## Match replacement to file info table

fns_df_ammended <- fns_df %>% 
  inner_join(replacement_table,
             c(key = "COMP_ID")) %>% 
  mutate(
    from = str_replace(key, "_(.+)", "_(\\1)"),
    to = paste0(CHEM_ID, ".C\\1"),
    new = str_replace(full_path, from, to) %>% 
      str_remove("^BIB.") %>% 
      str_replace("european-(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})", 
                  "BIB_EUR_SAIGE_GRCh37_\\1") %>% 
      basename()
  )

pwalk(
  fns_df_ammended, 
  function(full_path, new, ...) {
    new_path <- dirname(full_path) %>% 
      file.path("renamed", new)
    ## I use cpoy to keep the originals, you want `file.rename`
    file.copy(full_path, new_path)
  }
)



Hi thank you so much for this, I'll have a go. May I ask what is a keys file? Why would I need it? Don't I just need the text file [which I have, with all the relevant info of which COMPID goes with which CHEMID] and then a script to merge the CHEMID on to the file name based on the characters in the COMPID? Many thanks again for your help so far.

There is no keys file.  There is just your lookup file. What I did though, is to extract the relevant part from the filename (aka key) and merge that to my files names table. I propose that you run the code line by line and investigate the objects in between, you should see what  they do.
